# Android Studio - imageView displaying image in design editor, but not on emulator or device

Tags: android-studio, imageview

I'm trying to have an image display above a textView on this app and it will only display on the design editor in android studio. I have tried changing srcCompat to src in the XML, tried changing the image being used, and tried changing the constraints. I've asked friends who have no idea why its happening, and I'm totally at a loss

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/questionPicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionsLeftNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="99"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionsLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Questions remaining"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/questionsLeftNumber"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/questionsLeftNumber"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/questionsLeftNumber" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Submit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/questionsLeftNumber"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/questionsLeftNumber" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/question">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer2"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="answer2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer3"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="answer3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer0"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="answer0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="answer1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:text="Famous advice from an iconic mentor. Which fictional character really imparted this bit of sage wisdom?"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/questionPicture" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[What is displayed in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnJQY.png)

[What is displayed on either an emulator or device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBuwk.png)

Comment: It could be that your image is too large. Try a smaller one to see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"
```

This will only work for preview purposes. Attributes in the tools namespace are only enabled at design-time and removed at compile time.

You should use `app:srcCompat` instead.

Comment: Thanks my dude! I was literally just coming to edit the question that I had figured it out by digging through the documentation, so having someone actually confirm that I had come to the correct answer is lovely.

Comment: You're welcome. It's even better that you went further and found the answer.